# Does the torque in the Euler's rotation equations is taking along the world frame or the rotating frame?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

Euler's rotation equations state that:

M=Torque=IW'+WXIW

where W,W',I are taking along the rotating reference frame
is M also taking along the rotating reference frame?

Comment: The Euler rotation equations are $I\overrightarrow {\dot \omega }+\overrightarrow {\omega }\times I\overrightarrow {\omega }=\vec \tau $ , for a body fixed coordinate system all the components of the torque and the inertia tensor are in body system. You can use the equations also for a inertial system , then the components of the  tongue and the inertia tensor are in inertial system

Comment: The inertia tensor in inertial system is $ I_{0}=R^{T}I_{b}R$ where $I_b$ is the tensor in body system and R is the rotation matrix between body system and intertidal system