# Contradiction in Euler rotation Equation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

By Euler rotation Equation, torque
$$\tau (t)=I \omega '(t) + \omega(t) \times I \omega(t)$$

where $I$ is the inertia tensor in rotating frame and is constant;
$\omega(t)$ is the Angular velocity in the rotating frame, change with time;
$\tau (t)$ is the torque in the rotating frame;

but we know that 
$$\tau (t) = L'(t) = (I \omega (t))' = I \omega '(t);$$
as $I$ is constant and where $L$ is the Angular momentum in the rotating frame;

$W(t)\times IW(t)=0$ always???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Euler rotation equation,
$$
\vec{\tau} = \mathbf{I} \dot{\vec{\omega}} + \vec{\omega} \times \left(\mathbf{I} \vec{\omega} \right),
$$
implicitly refers to the description of the motion in a rotating reference frame, namely the reference frame rotating with the rigid body.  In such a reference frame, it is no longer true that $d\vec{L}/dt = \vec{\tau}$.

Comment: Can you prove why?

Comment: @GuyAb:  I'm not sure which aspect you want proved, but the derivations of this are in most intermediate-level classical mechanics texts.  See §11.8 of Thornton & Marion;  §5.5 of Goldstein;  or §10.7 of Taylor.

Comment: I am working on the solution of: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/493028/does-an-asymmetric-top-return-to-its-initial-position-orientation-while-rotati/493241?noredirect=1#comment1110833_493241

Comment: he use a rotation matrix U(t) to rotate I,W from rotating frame to world frame, can use it to rotate L and Torque also?

Comment: question 2: are all I,W,Torque are vectors taking along the rotating frame?

Comment: @GuyAb:  $\omega$, $\tau$, and $L$ are all vectors that can be expressed in either frame, and you can shift from one description to the other via the (time-dependent) transformation matrix $U$.  However, $I$ is a tensor and so has a different transformation law;  specifically, it's something like $I'_{ij} = U_{ik} U_{jl} I_{kl}$ (assuming Einstein summation convention.)

Answer (score 0):

Your second equation is a formula which is obtained for a certain reference frame.

On the other hand, your first one is relating two different frames.

Comment: what you mean? is any of I, W or Torque is not in the rotating frame that is fixed to the body?

Comment: You tell me, haha. But it looks so. Otherwise, why are you adding the $\omega \ \times$ term?

Answer (score 0):

**The Euler rotation equation**

$$
\vec{\tau} = \mathbf{I} \dot{\vec{\omega}} + \vec{\omega} \times \left(\mathbf{I} \vec{\omega} \right),
\tag 1$$

with 
$\frac{d}{dt}L=\vec{\tau}$
and 
$L=\mathbf{I}\,\vec{\omega}$

but if $\vec{\tau}=0$ then $L=\mathbf{I}\,\vec{\omega}=const.\quad $

thus equation (1):

$$
\vec{0} = \vec{0} + \vec{\omega} \times \left(\mathbf{I} \vec{\omega} \right),
\quad \surd$$

if the components of the angular momentum $L_b$,are given in body fixed coordinate system index $b$
then the time derivative of the angular momentum components $L_o$ in space system (index o) is:

$$\frac{d}{dt} L_o=\frac{d}{dt} L_b+\vec{\omega}\times L_b$$

now $\frac{d}{dt}L_o=\vec{\tau}=\vec{0}$ doesn't obtain that $\frac{d}{dt}L_b=\vec{0}$ 
thus $L_b$ is not conserved

**remark:**

the external torque $\vec{\tau}=\vec{r}\times \vec{F}$ is equal to zero if  the force 
$\vec{F}$ is parallel to the radius of the rotation point $\vec{r}$, this force is call central force.

Comment: I don't understand, assuming all vector/tensor in the right side of your equations (L,W,I) are taking along the rotating frame, does the left side (torque) is taking along the rotating frame or the world frame?

Comment: What is wrong in this $\overrightarrow {0}=\dfrac {d}{dt}\overrightarrow {L}_{b}+\overrightarrow {\omega }\times \overrightarrow {L}_{b}$ equation?

Comment: When it is = 0 it does not matter, but what if not? just want to be sure, see other comment and your from  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/494086/does-the-torque-in-the-eulers-rotation-equations-is-taking-along-the-world-fram?noredirect=1#comment1112317_494086

Comment: Of course all vector components must be taken in the same frame.